# coffeescript split string or default in one line

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, hubot

I'm currently checking for an environment variable, which may or may not exist, and assigning that to a variable or setting a default if it doesn't exist. I'm then splitting the string in a different line to get an array. I'm wondering if this can be done in a simple one liner (without having to double check the env var)

Currently doing:

```
deploy_rooms = process.env['HUBOT_DPLOY_ROOMS'] || "deployments"
deploy_rooms = deploy_rooms.split ','
```

could do this

```
deploy_rooms = (process.env['HUBOT_DPLOY_ROOMS'] || "deployments").split ','
```

but wondering if there's a nicer way?

Comment: you dont need to have it inside "()" it should work fine - plus - "could do this I think but not sure" try and see

Comment: yeh it does work, I'll edit the question

Comment: this is the cleanest it would get In my opinion.

Comment: @NetaMeta probably, I'll mark as answered

Answer (score 1):

yeh just do this

```
deploy_rooms = (process.env['HUBOT_DPLOY_ROOMS'] || "deployments").split ','
```